# Sparse index sets in Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I am new to pyomo.

I have the following classes:

```
MyList:
    def __init__(self,my_list= None, levels = None):
        if my_list is None:
            my_list= []
        self.my_list= my_list
        if levels is None:
            levels = []
        self.levels = levels 

MyDict:
    def __init__(self,my_dict= None, levels = None):
        if my_dictis None:
            my_dict= {}
            for lvl in levels:
                my_dict[lvl] = []
        self.my_dict = my_dict
        if levels is None:
            levels = []
        self.levels = levels 

MyElem:
    def __init__(self,my_attribute):
        self.my_attribute = my_attribute
```

The idea is that `MyList` contains a list of `MyDict`s and that a `MyDict` contains for each key `level` a value which is a list of `MyElem`.

Now in pyomo, I have created the following sets:

```
model.levels = Set(initialize = self.levels)
model.my_list= Set(initialize = self.my_list)
```

What I would like to create is a set `model.my_elem` corresponding to `MyElem`, in a way that I can create associated variables `model.x`, and such that I can then call `model.x[k,l,j]`, where `k` is a MyDict, `l is a level` and `j` is a `MyElem`

Comment: This is very confusing, and if you are new to `pyomo` you are asking for trouble with such a complicated setup.  Why can you not just make three sets (with better, representative names) and then just make `model.x` and triple index it?  Have you tried that?

Comment: I cannot (as far as I understand) because one set is indexed by the two others